# WKkwebview can't interactive with javascript in ios 9

Tags: javascript, ios9, wkwebview

I use the workspace of xcode to develop my app. H5 page is local in my project. I use wkwebview to add javascript code into the H5 page and show the h5 page in the app.In the iOS 10.3 everything is OK . In the iOS 9 the page also can show but it can't interactive. Click the button in the H5 page,it can't trigger the function of the iOS code. In the iOS10 it is ok.  Why it is.Can someone give me a advice?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the bug. In iOS 10, variable 'let' or variable 'var' of the javascript either is ok. But in iOS 9 , I use the 'let' cause go wrong.When I replace the 'let' by 'var', everything is ok.